# GitHub Enterpriseと(Enterpriseでない)Travis CIは連携できるのか

Tags: github, travis-ci

ドキュメントや設定が見当たらないのですが、そもそもできないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決。
Travis CIの仕様上できないとの回答が得られました。

Comment: 直接問い合わせ等を行った結果「仕様上出来ない」と判断されたのでしょうか？せっかくなので自己解決に至った情報をもう少し詳しく書いてもらうと、同じ疑問で困った人がこのページを見た際の手助けになるかと思います。

Comment: すみません。直接問い合わせを行い、現在の仕様上はできないという回答を得ました。
Enterprise版のTravis CIあるいはCircleCIを構築して実施することをオススメされました。